# select nth column in a table

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-table

I wanted to change the `width` of the third `td` in the below `table`

```css
#mytable table > tr > td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 600px !important;
}
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Can you please help me out

Comment: `#mytable table` won't work because that's attempting to select the table that is the child of an element with the id of mytable. You just need `#mytable`

Comment: Also most, if not all, browsers insert a `<tbody>` around the `<tr>` elements, so using the `tableSelector > tr` is also probably going to fail.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nkgyjbxu/   Please look into jsfiddle

Comment: Won't a simple `#mytable tr td:nth-child(3)` work?

Comment: @ThillaiNarayanan Your fiddle is funny. You put your CSS on the Javascript box. Here's the edited version: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nkgyjbxu/2/)

Comment: Thanks @PatrickGregorio Right version https://jsfiddle.net/nkgyjbxu/1/

Comment: @ThillaiNarayanan Your updated fiddle still doesn't work. I've updated it https://jsfiddle.net/nkgyjbxu/3/

Comment: @PatrickGregorio removed the ID, but i didn't update the fiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two errors:

1. Your selector: `#mytable` is already a `table` and has no `table` child,
   so use only `#mytable`
2. The `>` in `table > tr` will **not work** since the browser adds `tbody` by default,
   therefore `tr` is an immediate child of `tbody`

```css
#mytable{
  width:100%;
}
#mytable td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 600px; background:#eee;
}
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`#mytable table` means that the CSS is trying to find an element with the ID of `mytable` and within that element looking for a `<table>`.  You also do not need to be that specific; the following would achieve your goals:

`#mytable tr td:nth-child(3) { width: 600px; }`

Answer (score 0):

This should be **Visually** more clear to you

[image: Snapshot]

Below is Snippet

```css
.tblcommission{
  border:1px solid black;
}

.tblcommission thead tr td:nth-child(2){
  border:1px solid red;
  background-color:red;
  color:white;
}

.tblcommission tbody tr td:nth-child(2){
  border:1px solid black;
  background-color:blue;
  color:white;
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<table class="tblcommission">
<thead>
  <tr>
  <td>h1</td>
  <td>h2</td>
  <td>h3</td>
  <td>h4</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <tr>
  <td>111111</td>
  <td>222222</td>
  <td>333333</td>
  <td>444444</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
  <td>111111</td>
  <td>222222</td>
  <td>333333</td>
  <td>444444</td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
  <td>111111</td>
  <td>222222</td>
  <td>333333</td>
  <td>444444</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```